# OpenGL Translation

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to make translation on the object which is move down along y-axis. But the object didnt move along y-axis. It remain at the initial position that I set at 1.0f. May I know what is the problem? How can I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
void balls () {
glTranslatef(0.0f, ball, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
  glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
  glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);       // Center of circle
  int numSegments = 100;
  GLfloat angle;
  for (int i = 0; i <= numSegments; i++) { // Last vertex same as first     vertex
     angle = i * 2.0f * PI / numSegments;  // 360 deg for all segments
     glVertex2f(cos(angle) * ballRadius, sin(angle) * ballRadius);
  }
glEnd();

ball -= ySpeed; //move down

if (ball > -1.5f) {
    ball = 1.0f;
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: The code at the beginning of the file was important. If you want to clean it up, remove the bits that were relevant to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You start with `ball = 1`:

```
GLfloat ball = 1.0f; //position
```

then decrement by `0.01`:

```
GLfloat ySpeed = 0.010f;
ball -= ySpeed; //move down
```

Which gives us `ball == 0.99`. Then you do this:

```
if (ball > -1.5f) {
    ball = 1.0f;
}
```

Since `0.99 > -1.5`, `ball` is reset to `1`. Rinse and repeat.

---

To solve that, your comparison should reflect the operation you're doing (subtraction):

```
if (ball < -1.5f) { 
    ball = 1.0f;
}
```

Which can be read as *subtract* `ySpeed` from `ball` until *it falls below* `-1.5`.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to make my object looping. So, I use if (ball > -1.5f) {
    ball = 1.0f;
}